# problems with calendar extender controller in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, calendar

i am using a calendar extender  control in my asp.net web application. i want to disable this control while clicking on  a check box. i used disabled property of calendar extender. i set disabled =true . but i have  2 problems.

1. it do not desabling the textbox associated with calendar extender control
2. i am using a regular expression validator to validate the date. if calendar extender is disabled then the regular expression validator always fails. (i assume the regular expression validator  cant read the date when the calendar extender control is disabled)

i hope someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not disabling the Textbox, the Validator(use CompareValidator with datatype=Date) and the Extender in the CheckedChanged Event handler of the Checkbox on serverside?

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of regular expression validator, use compare validator, set the operator to datatypecheck and datatype to date that will help
- Disable the textbox along with the calender

Hope this will help